# VueJS: JSON objects are not showing in my code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have API that stores JSON data as shown in JSON body below... I wanted to show the data `amount` stored in `installments` but it didn't work good because its showing me each amount value two times and I couldn't figure out the problem here.

```js
{
  "response": [{
        "floors": [{
              "flats": [{
                    "status": "sold",
                    "price": "150000",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "end_date": "Not Set",
                    "buyer": "ella",
                    "buyer_phone_number": "002822128",
                    "receipt_number_field": "553108012022",
                    "size_unit": "M",
                    "_id": "61d9b61397e87e39832a5abb",
                    "flat_number": 1,
                    "description": "This is a newly created flat.",
                    "city": "NY",
                    "payment": {
                      "installment_payment": {
                        "installments": [{
                            "amount": "1344",
                            "date": "2022-01-13",
                            "is_paid": false
                          },
                          {
                            "amount": "444",
                            "date": "2022-01-24",
                            "is_paid": false
                          },
                          {
                            "amount": "44444",
                            "date": "2022-01-17",
                            "is_paid": false
                          }
                        ],
                        "remaining": "150000"
                      },
                      "paid_amount": "1234"
                    },
                    "floor": "61d9b61397e87e39832a5aba",
                    "building": "61d9b61397e87e39832a5ab9",
                    "size": "176.25",
                    "directions": " south",
                    "createdAt": "2022-01-08T16:04:43.557Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-01-08T16:22:29.220Z",
                    "__v": 0
                  },
```

`my code`:

```js
<div v-for="(flat,index) in Flats" :key="index">
<div v-for="(find,indexT) in flat.payment" :key="indexT" >
<div v-if="flat.payment.installment_payment">
 <div v-for="(find,indexT) in  flat.payment.installment_payment.installments" :key="indexT">
                <div v-if="find.amount >0">

                 <p> {{find.amount}}$  amount </p>
                                         
                                      </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

p.S: I stored my API data in array `Flats`

Comment: you stored response.floors.flats in variable Flats?

Comment: yes @FerryKranenburg

Comment: I think the duplicate index variable is the issue. Try changing the last indexT variable to something unique inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work, but it's untested.

You generally do not want to use `v-if` inside of `v-for`; instead, you should filter the data first and use the result in the `v-for` loop. [[reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for)]

Also, since each `flat` has an `_id` field, you can use that instead of the `index` for the top level `:key` attribute.

```html
<div v-for="flat in flatsWithPayments" :key="flat._id">
  <div v-for="(installment, index) in getInstallmentsWithPaymentGTZero(flat.payment.installment_payment.installments)" :key="index">
    <p> {{installment.amount}}$ amount </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, replace `Flats` with your data, but also note that in order to compare the payment amount, it needs to be converted with either `Number()`, `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

```js
// Flats = { ... }

export default {
  computed: {
    flatsWithPayments() {
      return Flats.filter(f => f.payment != undefined)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getInstallmentsWithPaymentGTZero(installments) {
      return installments.filter(i => Number(i.amount) > 0)
    }
  }
}
```